# Jquery Tabs in a MVC User Control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem with Jquery Tabs. On my MVC page, I have a form that returns a partial page (.ascx). This page has Jquery tabs on it, howerver all I get is the tab content without the tab. It looks like the partial page javascript code for the tab does not run,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { $("#tabs").tabs(); });
</script>
```

I tried to put this in the main page, but I get an error because "#tabs" does not exist on the page when it is first loaded.

Any ideas on getting this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading the partial via AJAX?  If so, put the code that generates the tabs in the AJAX callback instead of on the page.

```
$('#tabContent').load( '/controller/action', null, function() {
   $('#tabs').tabs();
});
```

With the MS Ajax helpers:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", new AjaxOptions { ..., OnSuccess = "doTabs", ...})) %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function doTabs() {
       $('#tabs').tabs();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Then, you'll want to add the tabs() function in the success callback specified in the AjaxOptions.

Comment: Will this still work if the Ajax.BeginForm can return a few different pages and only one of them has tabs?

Comment: If you don't have a #tabs element on the page, the selector won't match anything and the tabs won't be applied.